Foreground Service Location being killed by android after 5 mins of inactivity
First let me be clear about my project deails
Requirement : I need to send my user location to server constantly for about every minute
Problem : Android is killing my service after about 5 mins of inactivity
Inactivity in the sense - User opens the app ,we start sending location updates ,but user opens other app like Social media and use it ,but our app is still in background not killed.
Issue seen in device: Vivo V2141 Android Version : 13
Target SDK - 29
Permssions in manifest :
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />

my service :
<service
    android:name="LocationService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true"
    android:foregroundServiceType="location" />

How do I start service :
startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LocationService.class));
How do I make it foreground service :
In my service onCreate : I create a notification and call StartForeground to make it foreground
code :
private void generataeNotification() {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.1)
                    .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.s1))
                    .setContentText(getString(R.string.tracking_location))
                    .setOngoing(true)
                    .build();
            startForeground(R.id.location_service_notification_id, notification);
        } else {
            String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "channelId";
            String channelName = Constants.APP_NAME;
            NotificationChannel chan = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            chan.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
            chan.setSound(null, null);
            chan.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
            NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            assert manager != null;
            manager.createNotificationChannel(chan);
            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
            Notification notification = notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.d1)
                    .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.s1))
                    .setContentText(getString(R.string.tracking_location))
                    .setOngoing(true)
                    .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
                    .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
                    .build();
            startForeground(2, notification);
        }
    }

and How to I get location :
mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
mFusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, null);

mLocationRequest , mLocationCallback are basic callbacks you see in any code.
Additional Info : I provided all the permissions and I Kept logs on almost every callback ,
But after 5 mins as i said , Notification which we constructed to make it foreground is removed and no logs at all after that point.
No onDestroy log , no locationAvailability callback , nothing.
Absolutely no logs in any callback
Device didn't went to sleep mode or Doze mode since I'm actively using youtube , no point in battery optimisation because i kept my device in charging  , device is of 4+1 GB of Ram and only 2 apps are in recent list ( My app , YouTube ).
NOTE : I created another project with Target SDK 34 and wrote the same code with additional android 14 permissions , I noticed the same happening there also , I started location foreground service and normal foreground service , both are being stopped after 5 mins or so.
I am trying to understand why this is happenning ,as per official android documentation with provided permissions we should be able to run our services as foreground services without worring about it being killed unless doze mode ( in that too it shoudnt kill , since we show notification and make our services foreground)
Please help me understand the problem here, and any potential solutions.
Please Note our device is not in sleep mode or DOZE mode to use wakeLocks , battery optimasations , we indeed kept our device in charging while testing this.
EDIT :  I even tried work manager with whitelisting my app but its also of no use.
first workmanager worked for 2 hrs without any issue,
but after a day work manager also getting killed

Take a look at https://dontkillmyapp.com/
Vivo is listed there as one of the manufacturers that employ "app killer" apps in the name of battery saving

@IvanWooll but my guess is the issue is not with battery saving , i kept my app in whitelist , and my phone is in charging.
My point is it may not be due to battery related

does this happens on any other device/manufacturer? casue Xiaomi, vivo, Oppo, realme and other "typical chinese" devices oftenly carrying very modified Android system with additional custom "features" like more agressive app-background killer due to power consumtion or time in background, some custom permissions etc. At first check "vanilla" Android device, like Pixel or some other as-less-as-possibile modified OS, at least on another version of system from another manufacturer

you can double check if your app has location permission to "Allow all the time" or just "Allow only while using the app".

@snachmsm Thanks for responding , noted ur points , but we cant say not to use these devices to our users right.
When we deplyoed in prod we got around 10-15 issues related to this , from first pilot itself.
And please note when this issue was reproduced in lower environment by us
Battery perecentage : 100,
Ignoring battery optimisation / whitelisted : True,
Charging : Yes,
App in sleep or doze Mode : No,
no battery restrictions were there when we tested.

@AngelKoh Thanks for Responding ,
we gave allow all time permission , which is ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION.
although its not needed since we are using targed SDK : 29 and declared our foregroundService type as location in manifest,
but still not working

"...but we cant say not to use these devices to our users right...", If the device manufacturer changed things in how the OS handles background services even after the app has been whitelisted then there is nothing you can do. Killing a foreground service after 5 mins is not normal android behavior assuming there are no memory constraint issues where android will start to kill services. You should inform your users that are seeing this behavior and let them know the limitation with the device is because of the manufacturer

Xiaomi devices will kill foreground services when user closes the application from app switcher (Xiaomi is the worst) and you should ask Xiaomi users to manually exclude your application from being killed in battery saver or extra permissions in app details

SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW, It's my way of dealing with this kind of problem.

@user13776577 can you please help me in understanding the usage of SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW in not killing our services

A service with a visible overlay due to SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW is technically considered a foreground service. The system prioritizes keeping foreground services alive for a better user experience. This can slightly improve the chances of your service surviving longer. It can improve service survival chances, but it comes at a cost of battery drain and negative impact on user experience if overlay is not handled properly. Consider using Foreground Service and WorkManager. Check this for more info

There's no guaranteed way to prevent WorkManager from ever being killed, especially on devices with aggressive doze mode settings. Recheck 1. Aggressive Doze Mode 2. Heavy Resource usage 3. WorkRequest Constraints Not Met
